# How to typephint a return value to an IntEnum

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I want to annotate a function to indicate that it can only return values from an `IntEnum`

```
from enum import IntEnum
import random


class GoodIntegers(IntEnum):
    THE_ANSWER_TO_LIFE_THE_UNIVERSE_AND_EVERYTHING = 42
    DEADBEEF = 0xdeadbeef
    LEET = 1337
    
   
def f() -> GoodIntegers:
    return random.choice([42, 1337, 0xdeadbeef])
```

But mypy won't trust me that my source of integers is doing the right thing:

```
$ mypy test.py
test.py:12: error: Incompatible return value type (got "int", expected "GoodIntegers")  [return-value]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is there a workaround to tell mypy that I really really trust my source of integers to give me only values that match a value in my `IntEnum`?

In my realistic example, the source for the integers are the individual elements of a `bytes` string:

```
class OpCodes(IntEnum):
    ...


def get_ops_from_script(script: bytes) -> List[Tuple[OpCodes, Optional[bytes]]:
    ops = []

    while n < len(script):
        op: GoodIntegers = script[n]
        ... 
        # depending on the opcode some data may be extracted from the script
        # then n is incremented to find the next opcode
        ops.append((op, data))
    return ops
```

Comment: `int` and `GoodIntegers` are different types. You define `f() -> GoodIntegers`, but it returns a random element of the list... what do you expect? Return your type instead.

Comment: @alec_djinn I guess my question could be paraphrased as "how do I do the thing you just said?"
In my trivial example I could simply change a line to `return random.choice([GoodIntegers.THE_ANSWER_TO_LIFE_THE_UNIVERSE_AND_EVERYTHING, GoodIntegers.DEADBEEF, GoodIntegers.LEET])`, but in the more realistic case this would not work.

Comment: How do I cast the type in a way that makes mypy unbderstand what is happening?

Comment: @PiRK that's what you have to do, why would that not work?

Comment: you could do `op: GoodIntegers = GoodIntegers(script[n])`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks, that's what I was missing. I guess I need to read the doc for enums more thoroughly.

Comment: As an aside, I suggest not using an `IntEnum` but just a regular `enum.Enum`